# What was this helicopter photographed on a Chinese aircraft carrier?

Tags: helicopter, aircraft-identification, aircraft-carrier, china

I've read this [twit](https://twitter.com/Maxar/status/1268258165214392322)

Chinese carrier got photographed by a satellite.
[image]

On the nose you can find a helicopter and several people around it.

What helicopter is that?

Comment: The noise is strong enough to obscure any details smaller than "it lacks wings."

Answer (score 3):

Can't say for sure, but the size and shape (as far as can be determined from the picture) seems to match the Aerospatiale Super Frelon, which is built under license in China and is in use with the Chinese navy for shipboard operations under designation Z-8.

The image is of poor enough quality that a more precise determination isn't feasible, but the size and shape match the type and the type is in Chinese service (unlike similarly sized helicopters).

Answer (score 3):

It's really hard to tell from this photo but an [August 2019 photo](https://www.scmp.com/news/china/military/article/3021707/another-sea-trial-chinas-first-home-grown-aircraft-carrier) shows a [Changhe Z-18](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changhe_Z-18) for a similar sea trial.

[Wikipedia indicates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_aircraft_carrier_Shandong) PLAN Shandong only carries Z-18 and Z-9 but in this picture it seems too big to be a Z-9.

[image]